# Bootstrap4 navbar always collapsed

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angular, navbar

For some reason, the exact same code I have started working differently once I updated angular... here my navbar code

```
<nav *ngIf="authService.isLoggedin" class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
<button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<a class="navbar-brand" routerLink="home">Mavis</a>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="authService.isAdmin">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="settings">Settings</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="home">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="session">Session</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <button (click)="logout()" class="navbar-brand"><strong>Logout</strong></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

My problem is that the navbar is always collapsed, regardless of the width of the screen, this looks great on phone, but not on desktop. I'm sure i setup bootstrap with my angular 2 project properly.. but just to be sure, i added these into my 'angular-cli.json' file

```
"styles": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "styles.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "../node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.js",
    "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
  ],
```

Comment: can you replicate a plunker for this issue as it works for me check this [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts)

Comment: @RahulSingh if it helps, for some reason the navbar doesn't automatically collapse after selecting a link either

Comment: Had the same problem and found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45962428/8810998