# Bootstrap 4 navbar links are invisible but navbar brand appears

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

I have this code for my navbar but when I run it on my site the navbar links are hidden. The navbar brand name, test, does appear but I am unsure as to why the other links are hidden. Does anyone know a solution to this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
   <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
   </head>
   <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
         <div class="container">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">test</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
           <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
           <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
             <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
             <a class="nav-link" href="/products">Products</a>
            </li>
           </ul>
           <form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
           </form>
          </div>
         </div>
        </nav>  
  
  <!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `navbar-expand-*` classes don't exist in Bootstrap 4.0 alpha.6. Instead use `navbar-toggleable-*` or a newer version such as the latest 4.1.3:

https://www.codeply.com/go/k2jEkNyhg7

[Why is the Bootstrap 4 Navbar always collapsed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45962115/why-is-the-bootstrap-4-navbar-always-collapsed/45962428#45962428)